# Perform action after Dataflow pipeline has processed all data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to perform an action once a batch Dataflow job has finished processing all data? Specifically, I'd like to move the text file that the pipeline just processed to a different GCS bucket. I'm not sure where to place that in my pipeline to ensure it executes once after the data processing has completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you need to do this post pipeline execution. You could use side outputs to write the file to multiple buckets, and save yourself the copy after the pipeline finishes.

If that's not going to work for you (for whatever reason), then you can simply run your pipeline in [blocking execution](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#blocking-execution) mode i.e. use `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()`, and then just write the rest of your code (which does the copy) after that.

```java
[..]
// do some stuff before the pipeline runs
Pipeline pipeline = ...
pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
// do something after the pipeline finishes here
[..]
```

Comment: Thanks. Running the job with `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` does the trick. `waitUntilFinish()` doesn't seem to be available in the 1.x Java API.

Comment: Correct, it's not. You use the Blocking runner and wait/poll instead in 1.x

Comment: Thanks Polley. i was creating pipelines for such requirements, and this did my job!

Comment: would this still work if the pipeline is executed in streaming mode? The use case here would be if the pipeline was windowed for, say, 1hr intervals and we want to execute some logic after each window finishes.

Answer (score 2):

A little trick I got from reading the source code of apache beam's [`PassThroughThenCleanup.java`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/PassThroughThenCleanup.java).

Right after your reader, create a side input that 'combine' the entire collection (in the source code, it is the `View.asIterable()` PTransform) and connect its output to a `DoFn`. This `DoFn` will be called only after the reader has finished reading ALL elements.

P.S. The code literally name the operation, `cleanupSignalView` which I found really clever

Note that you can achieve the same effect using `Combine.globally()` (java) or `beam.CombineGlobally()` (python). For more info check out section 4.2.4.3 [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms)

Answer (score -1):

I think two options can help you here:

1) Use [**TextIO**](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/) to write to the bucket or folder you want, specifying the exact GCS path (for e.g. gs://sandbox/other-bucket)

2) Use [**Object Change Notifications**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) in combination with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/). You can find a good primer on doing this [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and the SDK for GCS in JS [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-resources-nodejs). What you will do in this option is basically setting up a trigger when something drops in a certain bucket, and move it to another one using your self-written Cloud Function.