# Execute a process exactly after BigQueryIO.write() operation

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline with a BigQuery table as sink. I need to perform some steps exactly after data has been written to BigQuery. Those steps include performing queries on that table, read data from it and write to a different table.

How to achieve the above? Should I create a different pipeline for the latter but then calling it after the 1st pipeline will be another problem I assume.

If none of the above work, is it possible to call another dataflow job(template) from a running pipeline.

Really need some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not explicitly supported by BigQueryIO. The only workaround is to use separate pipelines: start the first pipeline, wait for it to finish (eg. using `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()`), start the second pipeline (make sure to use a separate Pipeline object for it - reusing the same object multiple times is not supported).

Comment: Just to add - you wouldn't necessarily have to use another pipeline to achieve this. After the first pipeline finishes (`pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()`), then you could just drop back into using the BigQuery SDK. We do this a lot in our pipelines and the pattern works well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315157/perform-action-after-dataflow-pipeline-has-processed-all-data/44328850#44328850

Comment: @jkff How to make it work in case I'm creating templates? So will I have separate templates for the two pipelines? What if I wanted to create a single template that will run both pipelines?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible with templates.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I have been using with ***templates*** is writing the result of IO operations to a metadata file into a specific bucket, a cloud function (that is my *orchestrator*) gets triggered, and that, in turn, triggers the following pipeline. However, I tested it only with TextIO operations.
So, in your case:

- Perform BigQueryIO.write() operation
- Write its result to a file (xxx-meta-file) into a Cloud Storage bucket (xxx-meta-bucket) where you keep only Dataflow results - this is the last step of your pipeline
- Write an orchestrator Cloud Function that listens to created/modified objects in xxx-meta-bucket (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage))
- In the orchestrator, you will likely need some condition to check what file was actually created/modified
- Trigger the next pipeline accordingly (directly in the orchestrator or decouple it by triggering another cloud function responsible for starting that specific pipeline)

Pretty sure a similar approach can be easily replicated using PubSub instead of writing to buckets (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598451/5118339) for the second step in my list)