# How to notify when DataFlow Job is complete

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to know on GAE when dataflow job is completed.

I tries to make the following both pipeline

1.

```
 | 'write to bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)
 | WriteStringsToPubSub('projects/fakeprj/topics/a_topic')
```

2.

```
 | 'write to bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)
 | 'DoPubSub' >> beam.ParDo(DoPubSub())   # do Publish using google.cloud.pubsub
```

But the both above code produces the following error:

> AttributeError: 'PDone' object has no attribute 'windowing'

How to do procedure after WriteToBigquery?

note:
I execute dataflow using template via REST.
So, cannnot use `pipeline_result.wait_until_finish()`.

**Edit.**

Full stack is here.

```
File "<myPC_DIRPATH>/webapi-dataflow/pubsubtemplate.py", line 327, in <module>
   vital_data_export()
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>/webapi-dataflow/pubsubtemplate.py", line 323, in vital_data_export
   result = p.run()
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 382, in run
   return self.runner.run_pipeline(self)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\dataflow\dataflow_runner.py", line 285, in run_pipeline
   return_context=True)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 580, in to_runner_api
   root_transform_id = context.transforms.get_id(self._root_transform())
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\pipeline_context.py", line 60, in get_id
   self._id_to_proto[id] = obj.to_runner_api(self._pipeline_context)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 810, in to_runner_api
   for part in self.parts],
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\pipeline_context.py", line 60, in get_id
   self._id_to_proto[id] = obj.to_runner_api(self._pipeline_context)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 814, in to_runner_api
   for tag, out in self.named_outputs().items()},
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pipeline.py", line 814, in <dictcomp>
   for tag, out in self.named_outputs().items()},
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\runners\pipeline_context.py", line 60, in get_id
   self._id_to_proto[id] = obj.to_runner_api(self._pipeline_context)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pvalue.py", line 144, in to_runner_api
   self.windowing))
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\pvalue.py", line 128, in windowing
   self.producer.inputs)
 File "<myPC_DIRPATH>\webapi-dataflow\venv\dstobq_test\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\ptransform.py", line 443, in get_windowing
   return inputs[0].windowing
AttributeError: 'PDone' object has no attribute 'windowing'
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Thx for your comment.I add full stack.

Comment: The error shows as "AttributeError: 'PDone' object has no attribute 'windowing' ". We can see that the attribute name is 'PDone' which is supposed to have an attribute called 'windowing' but is missing.
Could you please let me know how 'PDone' was introduced into your pipeline and why it doesn't have the expected 'windowing' attribute?

Comment: I don't handled "PDone" and 'windowing'.WriteToBigQuery send "PDone" to next pipeline.

Comment: You have mentioned that you are not using "PDone" in your code. However, this error means that somewhere, your code is using it and therefore, you might need to share your code so we can have the full context. If you are sure it is not related to your code I would propose you open a bug using the "Create new Cloud Dataflow issue", on "public issue tracker" found here : https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU CANNOT**

It's evident that PDone is the last stage of your pipeline and applying wait for done for this is not necessary.

PInput and PDone  are classes supported by Apache Beam which indicates source and sink respectively. If you are trying to execute something after BigQuery write, it is not possible unless you run two different dataflow jobs in series.

If you are looking for running them in series, checkout Apache Airflow.

Comment: For running async jobs in series, look specifically at Dataflow Sensors: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#sensors

Answer (score 4):

In java this is what I did to publish a "done" event to PubSub at the end of a dataflow pipeline, where the output of the pipeline is writing to BigQuery. Hopefully there's equivalent in Python..

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = data.apply("ConvertToTableRow", ParDo.of(new ConvertToRow()));
// Normally this would be the end of the pipeline..
WriteResult writeResult = rows.apply("WriteToBQ", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(...);
// Transformations after this will be done AFTER all rows have been written to BQ
rows.apply(Wait.on(writeResult.getFailedInserts()))
    // Transforms each row inserted to an Integer of value 1
    .apply("OnePerInsertedRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Integer>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            c.output(Integer.valueOf(1));
        }
    }))
    // https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Sum.java#L51
    // Combines a PCollection of Integers (all 1's) by summing them. 
    // Outputs a PCollection of one integer element with the sum
    .apply("SumInsertedCounts", Sum.integersGlobally())
    .apply("CountsMessage", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, PubsubMessage>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String messagePayload = "pipeline_completed";
            Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
            attributes.put("rows_written", c.element().toString());
            PubsubMessage message = new PubsubMessage(messagePayload.getBytes(), attributes);
            c.output(message);
        }
    }))
    .apply("PublishCompletionMessage", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(/* output topic */));
```

Comment: This is a really good tip/hint. I tested it and works well. Kudos.

Comment: `writeResult.getFailedIntersts`returns the TableRows that dindn't made into BQ. Does this code only work if the writtings into BigQuery fail?

Comment: can this  above  code  be  used  for  bigquery  insert  successfully ? meaning  if  it  can  be  used  used  for  getting  acknowledgement  on  succesfull  bq  insert

Comment: This answer was fundamental for me to solve a problem I was having but there was something missing. @twang's code was not working for me when I was doing writes using the FILE_LOAD (or DEFAULT for bounded pipelines); it was firing too early. I swapped out the `writeResult.getFailedInserts()` for `writeResult.getSuccessfulTableLoads()` and it worked like a charm.