# How to create dependency between tasks in Apache beam python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am new to apache beam and exploring python version of apache beam dataflow. I want to execute my dataflow tasks in certain order but it executes all tasks in parallel mode. How to create task dependency in apache beam python?

Sample Code: (in this below code sample.json file contains 5 rows)

```
import apache_beam as beam
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class Sample(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        logging.info(self.index)
        return pcoll

class LoadData(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, context):
        logging.info("***")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

    (pipeline
        | "one" >> Sample(1)
        | "two: Read" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('sample.json')
        | "three: show" >> beam.ParDo(LoadData())
        | "four: sample2" >> Sample(2)
    )
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
```

I expected it will execute in order one, two, three, four. But it is running in parallel mode.

output of above code:

```
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the 
default runner: DirectRunner.
INFO:root:1
INFO:root:2
INFO:root:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.
INFO:root:***
INFO:root:***
INFO:root:***
INFO:root:***
INFO:root:***
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by executing this in sequence? Also, I'm not sure what your "Sample" transform is supposed to do: as implemented, it does nothing. Also keep in mind that, much like a database query plan, a pipeline is first constructed (that's when you're seeing the logging from expand()), and then optimized by the runner and executed (that's when you're seeing "***").

Comment: @jkff I want to load data from biquery to elasticsearch. In my sample transform, I am doing operations like creating, reindexing, deleting elasticsearch indexes. So first i need to create an temp index, second loading data and to ES temp index, third reindex it, fourth delete my temp index. So I want to execute all these task in ordered manner. but here creating, reindexing and deleting tasks are executed first and finally load data has executed. (you can see logs "*****" showed at last)

Answer (score 2):

As per [Dataflow's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pipelines):

> When the pipeline runner builds your actual pipeline for distributed
>   execution, the pipeline may be optimized. For example, **it may be more
>   computationally efficient to run certain transforms together, or in a
>   different order**. The Dataflow service fully manages this aspect of
>   your pipeline's execution.

Also as per [Apache Beam's documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/#bundling-and-persistence):

> The APIs emphasize processing elements in parallel, which makes it
>   difficult to express actions like “assign a sequence number to each
>   element in a PCollection”. This is intentional as such algorithms are
>   much more likely to suffer from scalability problems. Processing all
>   elements in parallel also has some drawbacks. Specifically, **it makes
>   it impossible to batch any operations, such as writing elements to a
>   sink or checkpointing progress during processing**.

So the thing is that Dataflow and Apache Beam are parallel by nature; they were designed to deal with embarrassingly parallel use cases and are maybe not the best tool if you require that operations are executed in an specific order. As @jkff pointed out, Dataflow will optimize the Pipeline in such a way that it parallelizes the operations in the best possible way.

If you really need to execute each of the steps in a consecutive order, the workaround is to use a [blocking execution](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#blocking-execution) instead, using [the `waitUntilFinish()` method](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/create-your-pipeline/#running-your-pipeline) as explained in this other [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328850/4482491). However, my understanding is that such an implementation would only work in a Batch Pipeline, as Streaming Pipelines would be consuming data continuously and therefore you cannot block the execution to work on consecutive steps.